# XPath: limit scope of result set

Tags: xpath

Given the XML

```
<a>
    <c>
        <b id="1" value="noob"/>
    </c>
    <b id="2" value="tube"/>
    <a>
        <c>
            <b id="3" value="foo"/>
        </c>
        <b id="4" value="goo"/>
        <b id="5" value="noob"/>
        <a>
            <b id="6" value="near"/>
            <b id="7" value="bar"/>
        </a>
    </a>
</a>
```

and the Xpath 1.0 query

```
//b[@id=2]/ancestor::a[1]//b[@value="noob"]
```

The Xpath above returns both node ids 1 and 5.  The goal is to limit the result to just node id=1 since it is the only `@value="noob"` element that is a descendant of the same `<a>` that (`//b[@id=2]`) is also a descendant of.

In other words, "Find all **b** elements who's value is "noob" that are descendants of the **a** element which also has a descendant whose id is 2, but is not the descendant of any other **a** element".  How's that for convoluted?  In practice the id number and values would be variable and there would hundreds of node types.

If the id=2, we would expect to return element id=1 not id=5 since it is contained in another a element.  If the id=4, we would expect to return id=5, but not id=1 since it is not in the first ancestor a element as id=4.

**Edit:**
Based on the comments of Dimitre and Alejandro, I found [this](http://sweatte.wordpress.com/syntax/xml-tips/xpath-tips/) helpful blog entry explaining the use of count() with the | union operator as well as some other excellent tips.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simpler solution than the currently accepted answer and for an understandable explanation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//b[@value='noob']
      [count(ancestor::a[1] | //b[@id=2]/ancestor::a[1]) = 1]
```

**Explanation**:

The second predicate assures that both `b` elements have the same nearest ancestor `a`.

**Remember**: In XPath 1.0 the test for node identity is:

```
count($n1 | $n2) = 1
```

Comment: Succinct, clear and and actually answered the question.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Laramie: As @Dimitre already knows, Set identity is formaly proved by the simetric membership. In XPath that would be `count($A|$B)=count($B) and count($B|$A)=count($A)` or the same `count($A|$B)=count($B) and count($B)=count($A)`. As long as you can assume that A and B are **singleton**, then you can reduce this to the provided `count($A | $B) = 1`

Comment: @Alejandro:  I wasn't aware that symmetric union could be applied in XPath.  It makes perfect sense now that I see it.  Thank you for the follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

First, this

> is there some way to limit the result
>   set to the `<b>` elements that are ONLY
>   the children of the immediate `<a>`
>   element of the start node
>   (`//b[@id=2]`)?

```
//b[@value='noob'][ancestor::a[1]/b/@id=2]
```

It's not the same as:

> Starting at a node whose id is equal
>   to 2, find all the elements whose
>   value is "noob" that are descendants
>   of the immediate parent c element
>   without passing through another c
>   element

Wich is:

```
//c[b/@id=2]//*[.='noob'][ancestor::c[1][b/@id=2]]
```

Besides these expressions, when you are dealing with "context marks" you can use the set's membership test as in:

```
$node[count(.|$node-set)=count($node-set)]
```

I leave you its use for this case as an exercise...

Comment: You are correct, I mispoke when I said, "parent c element without passing through another c element".  I intended to say, "parent a element without passing through another a element" as a clarification which missed the mark.  The XML in reality consists of hundred of node types in a highly unstructured format.  Porting that here has been a challenge.  Please see edits.  I would welcome an elaboration on "you can use the set's membership test as in..".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`//b[@id=2]/ancestor::a[1]//b[@value="noob" and not(ancestor::a[2]=//b[@id=2]/ancestor::a[1])]` ?
that works only for your case though, not sure how generic it should be!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the XML above is a super-simplified representation of what would be encountered in production.  The structure will be based on human language and will be extremely variable.  Hard-coded paths unfortunately won't work.