# (XPATH) Limit the scope of "Ancestor"

Tags: xml, xpath

Can I limit the scope of "Ancestor"?
For example,

```
1...<div itemtype="product" itemprop="name">
2... <div itemtype="product">
3...   <div itemtype="List"> 
4...     <span itemprop="name"> </span>
5...  </div>
6...   <span itemprop="name"> </c>
7... </div>
8...</div>
```

Condition: 
1. Select nodes *[@itemtype="product' and not(@itemprop)]
2. Under this childnodes, select itemprop, but between them, there's no new itemtype, in this case only line 6 should be selected.

```
I used this code, but not working due to ancestor nodes
//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop) and contains(@itemtype, '/Product')]//*[@itemprop='name' and count(ancestor::*[contains(@itemtype, 'schema.org/Product')])=count(ancestor::*[@itemtype])]
```

How can I exclude the top nodes from ancestor searching?

```
1...<div itemtype="product" itemprop="name"> --> ignore this line
-------------------------------------------> 
2... <div itemtype="product">
3...   <div itemtype="List"> 
4...     <span itemprop="name"> </span>
5...  </div>
6...   <span itemprop="name"> </c>
7... </div>
8...</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. What exactly do you want to "ignore", and in what way? It's not clear what your goal or expected results are.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks for your comment. I edited my code to be specific.

Comment: So you want to select a thing _A_ that has an `itemprop` property, that's a descendant of a thing _B_ that has an `itemtype` property of "product" and no `itemprop` of its own, but only if there is no thing with an `itemtype` property between _A_ and _B_? (And the problem you're having is that you haven't implemented the "between" part, so _A_ is triggering the exemption.) Blimey, that's convoluted. Where did you find this schema?!

Comment: Can you add an intermediate step that only selects nodes that don't have an `itemtype` property? I don't really see why you need any of the ancestor stuff. But I'm not an xpath expert.

Comment: Ah, nah, you can't because (e.g. in this case) there is no intermediate node. Meh.

Comment: Still think ancestor is the wrong approach though. Can you use two expressions and merge the results? `//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop) and contains(@itemtype, 'product')]/[@itemprop='name']` and `//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop) and contains(@itemtype, 'product')]//*[not(@itemtype)]//*[@itemprop='name']` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
//*[@itemtype='product'][not(@itemprop='name')]/descendant-or-self::*[1]
```

Output:

```
 <div itemtype="product">
   <div itemtype="List"> 
      <span itemprop="name"> </span>
   </div>
   <span itemprop="name"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and time. However, the case was just simplified, not the exact case. I edited my post to add more details, so the problem is due to nested "itemtype without itemprop" Category is determined by this "itemtype without itemprop" and subcategory is determined by "itemtype with itemprop" on their childnodes. This code //*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop) and contains(@itemtype, 'Product')]//*[@itemprop and count(ancestor::*[contains(@itemtype, 'Product')])=count(ancestor::*[@itemtype])] works well if there's no '<div itemtype="Product" itemprop="mainEntity">'

Comment: The case is a bit similar to these two cases: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614010/xpath-element-have-not-specific-parent-between-final
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651349/xpath-limit-scope-of-result-set?rq=1

Comment: //*[@itemprop='name' and count(ancestor::*[not(itemprop) and @itemtype= 'Product'])=count(ancestor::*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)])]

This code works, but I don't have confidence that this code is well-coded.

Comment: @hiyo - Unfortunately, this is the wrong way to ask questions on SO. By totally changing your original xml, this answer and all the comments above became meaningless to future readers. You have effectively asked a new question, not edited an existing one. You should probably revert your question to its original form, and post the new code with the exact case as a new question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I reverted my question to its original form. Sorry for that and thanks for your solution :)

Comment: @hiyo - No problem. Your original question was a good one (I'll upvote it now), but so is your new one - so please post it, too.